# How can I create a tooltip to show a chart series in Slate?

Tags: palantir-foundry, foundry-slate

I built a chart and it turned out chaotic because it had too many series in the legend. Therefore, I want to use the tooltips to show the series title, so that it looks tidy. But I am not sure what is the best way to achieve that.

The goal is that when you hover over a color band on the bar chart the correct title shows up. Below is an example of what it currently looks like, with too many series in the legend.
[image: confusing stacked bar chart]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can turn on tooltips using the miscellaneous tab of your chart menu. Then, input the value of `{{w_chart.hover.series}}`.

[image: Input area in slate]

Comment: It's often also helpful, in the case with a chart showing many series, to construct your own legend using an HTML widget. The necessary HTML can be generated dynamically in a Slate function. This approach provides more customization than the built in legend when needed. There is sample HTML and CSS styling in the Slate Reference Examples.